# How to fix PS3 error 80010514 (An error occured during start operation) in 2023?

Tags: technical-issues, ps3

I have here a fat PS3, 60GB, A-model that has worked reliably until recently.

I didn't buy/play many PS3 games back in the day. Since second-hand copies of PS3 games are dirt cheap these days, I've decided to expand on my physical Playstation library (given the news about the PS3/Vita stores closing down).

History of my PS3:
Bought the 60GB A-Model from GameStop used and the warranties that came with it back in 2010. Between then and 2012, I've had it replaced under GameStop's warranty 3 times for the YLOD problem. The 3rd unit I received in 2012 (still own today) has worked reliably since then (though I've put extremely light use on it playing mostly PS classics and PS2 games whenever I wanted to revisit something.

In 2020 when that-global-contagion started, I decided to revisit FFXIII, and discovered that the disc reader couldn't read Blu-ray discs. I researched the cause and installed an aftermarket disk reader I bought from Amazon (the whole unit, not just the laser), and the pitifully small PS3 library I had at the time all worked.

Now fast-forward to today, I've been going around getting my hands on several different PS3 games and discovered recently that a few I picked up present this 80010514 error when I try to start the game. So far it's only 2 games.

What I've tried so far:
I researched the cause on this and found the error could be any of these:

- Disc is damaged and cannot be read.
- Disc reader is damaged and needs replacement.
- HDD has a faulty sector.
- Firmware could be corrupt.

It cannot be the disc itself because it looks fine. Another PS3 disc I have that is in worst condition of all I own works just fine. Though, these 2 games that present the error I bought together from a random seller at a flea market. Do PS3 discs corrupt from "exposure" to "something", or could these be counterfeit? I don't know. Something seems sus that *these two games* from the same seller are the only ones with the problem.

It cannot be the disc reader because I just replaced the whole drive. Unless maybe this particular brand from Amazon isn't reliable?

It cannot be a bad sector on the HDD because the error appears immediately after inserting the disc, so it never prompts to update or install. I tried updating the 2 games anyway. Same error. I also followed this guide to restore the file system. Same error. I suppose a failing HHD could just cause undefined behavior in general. It's still the original 60Gb drive from 2006, so I guess it might be time to replace it.

It could be bad firmware, but how could I determine this?

I suppose next thing I could try is rebuilding the database, and if that doesn't work, then the nuclear option: system restore / reformat.

Anything else I could try? Is there a way to completely reinstall firmware if system restore doesn't do that?

Most of the articles I've read so far dated at least 10 years ago seem to indicate that at this point in troubleshooting the owner should contact Sony for repair or replacement. I doubt they'll want to deal with a PS3 in 2023, lol.

I'm on the latest OS version of the PS3: 4.89. Never been jailbroken.

Comment: Id say the 'look just fine' doesnt tell much. If there is a visible scratch, but its at the right place, the CD might still read. But a very small, almost invisible scratch somewhere critical (like on the part of the disc that is the anti piracy) it could spell doom.

Comment: But yeah you seem to have tried every solution i've seen in my quick search. Contacting sony to save your PS3 seems your only solution.